# identify the component from which the ajax listener is triggered

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have 2 inputText components:

```
<h:inputText id="inputCode">
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{mbean.inputListener}"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="inptValue"> 
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{mbean.inputListener}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

and in the managed bean:

fields:

```
long inputCode;
String inputText;
```

the listener:

```
public void inputListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe) {
  UIInput uiinput = (UIInput)abe.getSource();
  if(the listener is triggered by the inputText with id="inputCode") {
     inputCode = (long)uiinput.getValue();
  } else {
     inputText = String.valueOf(uiinput.getValue());     
  }
}
```

The question is: How can I differentiate from what inputText is the listener triggered to know in what field to save the value? 
I don't want to create a listener for each inputText.

I can do it by the component id, using component.id, but how can I call the listener with that parameter while it has 2 parameters: the AjaxBehaviorEvent and another would be the component id?

Comment: get the id from the component like you already almost do in pseudo code

Comment: Well, good point, but how can I pass the component id as argument to the listener? By using listener=#{mbean.inputListener(component.id)} would not work, because the inputListener has a parameter AjaxBehaviorEvent. If I would have the signature inputCodeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe, String componentId), how can I call this method?

Comment: you don't, it is already there un the uiinput (maybe you need to upcast it)

Comment: Not really an answer... I'd simply compare the input values with the currently (previously) values stored in the managed bean

Comment: Thank you guys. Kukeltje I used your advice. I don't see your advice as answer to accept it. (how can I accept it?)

Answer (score 0):

The id is already present on the `uiinput`. You could have seen this by looking at the api for `UIInput` So all you need to do is decide whether you need to use the id or clientId. The latter is prefixed with all id's of parent namingcontainers.

```
public void inputListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe) {
  UIInput uiinput = (UIInput)abe.getSource();
  if(uiinput.getId().equals("inputCode")) {
     inputCode = (long)uiinput.getValue();
  } else {
     inputText = String.valueOf(uiinput.getValue());     
  }
}
```

Should do the trick.